# How can i get data outside a foreach loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json

I want to get the value of my uid outside my foreach. How can i do it.  .Please help

this is my code

```js
var conf_url = "https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007";

       getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(obj){
           document.write(obj['uid'])
        });
    });
// i want to get the value of uid here
// I WANT TO GET THE VALUE OF UID HERE
     function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: conf_uri,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonpCallback: 'callback',
          contentType: "application/javascript",
          success: function(data) {
            handleData(data);
            console.log(data);
          }
        });

      }
```

this is my json data which is `https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007`

```
[{"id":8,"uid":"0090000163","cid":"0090000007","extension":"202","secret":"Myojyo42f!","leader":true,"simultaneous":false,"confbridge_id":6,"created_at":"2015-08-18 09:22:20","updated_at":"2015-08-18 09:22:20"},{"id":11,"uid":"0090000165","cid":"0090000007","extension":"204","secret":"Myojyo42f!","leader":false,"simultaneous":false,"confbridge_id":6,"created_at":"2015-08-18 09:45:36","updated_at":"2015-08-18 09:45:36"}]
```

Comment: Which `uid`? You appear to have multiple ones. Do you want to get them all out in an array? You could use `map` instead of `forEach` then.

Comment: Hello @Xufox. I want to get them all out in an array. How will i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a global variable

```
    var newVariable = [];

    getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(obj){
           newVariable.push(obj['uid']);
        });
    });
```

`newVariable` is now accessible outside foreach, but check your assignment, you are using loop so expected that you have multiple values.

Comment: @arem how did you implement it?

Comment: ahm . . I want to get the value outside . . foreach . .

Comment: i mean, the global variable one, try also to log your `obj` variable to see its contents, use console.log

Comment: when i access the value outside foreach . . only the last value appear.

Comment: @arem yah because the variable is not an array, you should put it in an array to capture all values, i edited my answer to implement it as an array

Answer (score 2):

**note:** first of all you have to add global array variable. javascript contain a **.push** function it will be add your object one be one

```
var globalArray=[];
function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: conf_uri,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonpCallback: 'callback',
          contentType: "application/javascript",
          success: function(data) {
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    globalArray.push( data[i]);
}
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a function for it?

```
var conf_url = "https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007";

       getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(obj){
           document.write(obj['uid']);
           myVal(obj['uid']);
        });
    });

// I WANT TO GET THE VALUE OF UID HERE
function myVal (var uid)
{

  console.log(uid);
  //do something
}
     function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: conf_uri,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonpCallback: 'callback',
          contentType: "application/javascript",
          success: function(data) {
            handleData(data);
            console.log(data);
          }
        });

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets all `uid`s into an Array:

```
getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
    data.map(function(obj){
       return obj.uid;
    });
});
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new Array based on another one. The function returns whatever you’re looking for (`obj.uid`).

Comment: Well, `data.map(…);` creates an array with the `uid`s… do you want to use the Array outside the function within `getParticipant` — is that what you mean? Just use the array outside of `data.map(…);` and inside `getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {…});`. I guess, this is an asynchronous function, so you kinda have to do it this way.

Comment: yes i want to use the array outside the function within getParticipant